# How to get the device contain applciation names

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which I need to get the list of applications installed on the device.  How can I get the list of installed applications on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot obtain such list, maybe you could if your device was jailbroken, but in legal ways you cannot obtain such info

Comment: On ALL iOS devices. YOUR app knows ONLY about itself. And no other apps

Comment: app is sandboxed with its resources and its local view of the system, no access whatsover is granted to query the outside world